# libvlc git clone 2.0.6

Tags: git, vlc, libvlc, vlc-android

I need libvlc 2.0.6 but when I clone the link bellow and compile I get **libvlc-3.0.0-2.1.2.aar**.

Is it possible to target a specific version when cloning git ?

git url: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *normal* way to do things is to clone the whole repository (which gets you the entirety of history -- all versions, all tags, etc) and then check out the specific version you want afterwards:

```
git clone https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android.git
cd vlc-android
git checkout 2.0.6
```

---

You can also tell clone to check out a specific version as it works; note that this still copies all of history down from the server:

```
git clone -b 2.0.6 https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android.git
```

---

You can also create a *shallow* clone, which **doesn't** copy down the rest of history, and only gets the specific version you want:

```
git clone -b 2.0.6 --depth 2 https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android.git
```

"depth 2" separates the changes in the commit tagged as 2.0.6 itself from those made prior; one could use "depth 1" if that weren't important.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Do you happen to know how to embed one of the following with Grgit.clone() ?

Comment: Never even heard of "Grgit".

Answer (score 1):

You've got tags that are made for that. Just check out the one you want. I see that there's one for the version you want.

`git checkout 2.0.6`